# Inno Setup ShellExec privileges

Tags: permissions, inno-setup, shell-exec

I have an InnoSetup project that launches an application when it's done with `ShellExec`. The issue is my installer escalates when it launches, but I want my launched application to run non escalated. Is this possible some way?

```
procedure LaunchApplication(shortcut: String);
var
  ErrorCode: Integer;
begin
  ShellExec('', ExpandConstant('{userprograms}\' + shortcut),'', '', SW_SHOW, ewNoWait, ErrorCode);
end;
```

Comment: You mean your installer runs in *elevated* (administrator's) mode - right? Or what do you mean by *my installer escalates* ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here I assume you are using

```
[Setup]
PrivilegesRequired=admin
```

to elevate the installer (UAC)

To run any program in non-elevated mode use **ExecAsOriginalUser** function:

> Prototype:
>
> function ExecAsOriginalUser(const Filename, Params, WorkingDir:
>   String; const ShowCmd: Integer; const Wait: TExecWait; var ResultCode:
>   Integer): Boolean; Description:
>
> Executes the specified executable or batch file, using the (normally
>   non-elevated) credentials of the user that started Setup initially.
>   See Exec and the [Run] section flag runasoriginaluser for more
>   information. Remarks:
>
> This function is not supported at uninstall time.
>
> In very unusual failure cases (e.g. if the initial Setup process died
>   unexpectedly), it is possible for this function to raise an exception
>   instead of just returning False.

Comment: It seems OP is possibly opening a shortcut (maybe a *.lnk file; weird, I know, but maybe it's just a bad name of the parameter). If that is so, the `ShellExecAsOriginalUser` must be used.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. I have seen this before but forgot about it. I am launching an lnk file. It is probably slightly unconventional but it is a Silverlight application so the shortcut contains the id and such, making this the easiest route.

Answer (score 1):

If you use a `[Run]` entry with the `postinstall` flag (so that a checkbox appears on the Finished page), then running non-elevated is the default behaviour.  (You can also set this for non-`postinstall` entries by using the `runasoriginaluser` flag.)

Note however that both this and the `ExecAsOriginalUser` function etc do not *guarantee* that they run non-elevated -- if the installer is originally run from an elevated context (eg. elevated command prompt, another elevated installer, or user right click Run As Administrator) then the "original user" is also the elevated user.  But in these cases you can assume the user is getting what they asked for.